# Oracle connection information for Play framework

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, playframework

I am developing a Java application in play framework and the back end of the application is Oracle. My database does not have a SID instead, it uses service ID. Also I am using Ebean in the application. This is my connection information in `application.conf` file.

```
db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:PORT/SERVICE_NAME"
db.default.user=USERNAME
db.default.pass=PASSWORD
```

Where I can specify the database name?

Answer (score 0):

when you insert correct information about ip port and db schema it should work fine. The one thing that it missing here is:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to include above driver information in my question. Actually this line is in my code already. But it does not work. Could you please let me know where to specify DB schema or the database name. Please send me an example.

Comment: this is an example:
    db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//127.0.0.1:1521/sidName"
    db.default.user=user
    db.default.password="your password"